# getchar() doesn't pass EOF and Ctrl+Z doesn't terminate the program on Cygwin

Tags: c, eof, getchar

Here is a simple program, counting strings, symbols and words.

Everything is ok with the computation, using Cygwin.

But while launching, after input values, the program doesn't print `nc`, `nw`, `nl` and wait for entering further values.

Changing `EOF` to 13 (Enter) doesn't help anyway.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is useful too: the program is stopping, writing `[n]+  Stopped`, where 'n' is always different number.

The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0


int main () {

    char c;
    int state;
    int nc, nw, nl;
    state = OUT;    

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        nc++;

        if (c == 'n') 
            nw++;


        if (c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == '\t') 
            state = OUT;
        else if (state = OUT){
            state = IN;
            nw++;
        }

    }
    printf ("%d %d %d", nc, nl, nw);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Warning: unused variable `nl` !

Comment: It should be `int c;`

Comment: `if (c == '\n') nl++;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getchar` returns `int`, not `char`. It has to do this because it can either return a character value or return the special value `EOF` to indicate the end of the input file. Since `EOF` has to be different from all values of the `char` type, it does not have the type `char`. So you need to define the variable that contains its return value as an `int`, not as `char`.

On some platforms, the `char` type is signed, and the `getchar` function does not in fact return the character value, but the character value wrapped around to a non-negative value. In practice, what this means is that ASCII characters are unchanged but, on some platforms, non-ASCII characters are transformed to a value between 128 and 255 instead of between -128 and -1. So in general you need to cast the return value of `getchar` to an `char` when you use it as a character. On platforms where the `char` type is unsigned, this doesn't change anything, but on platforms where the `char` type is signed, it is necessary to avoid character 255 being mistaken as the end of the file.

```
int c;
…
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    …
    if (c == 'n') /* ok because 'n' is part of ASCII and thus always positive */
        …
    if ((char)c == some_other_char) /*cast needed in general*/
        …
}
```

In Cygwin, like in other Unix-like systems, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of a line to signal the end of the input. Under Windows, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (under Cygwin, again like in other Unix-like systems, that instead suspends the programs: it's stopped, but can be resumed with the command `bg`). Neither of these send a control character to the program, they send an end-of-file indication which C's `getchar` implementation translates to the `EOF` value.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. But anyway ctrl+D doesn't help. Did I understamd you right- pressing ctrl+D, then start inputting, then pree Enter?

Comment: @DanielChepenko No, press Enter, then Ctrl+D.

Comment: @mafso Wooops. Been doing embedded stuff for too long… (`stdio`? Far too high-level!) Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the variables which you use to count:

```
  int nc = 0, nw = 0, nl = 0;
```

When you don't do that they get random values.

Also, your logic for counting words is wrong.

By `else if (state = OUT)` you probably meant `else if (state == OUT)`.

Comment: Changed initialization. Doesn't help anyway. What is wrong with logic?

Comment: found mistake in first condition change nw to nl, and in else if condition State==Out

Comment: But that doesn't help solving my problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure it helps. What's the point of my giving you the whole program? You won't learn anything in that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#define IN 1  
#define OUT 0
int main()
{
   int c, nl, nw, nc, state; //c is an int not a char        
   state = OUT;
   nl = nw = nc = 0;   // initialize variables to 0
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
       ++nc;
       if (c == '\n') // if c is a newline character 
           ++nl;     //increment no of lines
       if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
           state = OUT;
       else if (state == OUT) // == for comparing
       {
           state = IN;
           ++nw;
       }
    }
   printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
return 0;
}
```

Your program is supposed to look like the above one. `c` is an `int` and not a `char` because `getchar` converts the input to `unsigned char` and since it cannot hold negative values and since `EOF` holds -1 , the `while` loop will never end.

It ends when you press CTRL+Z(in windows else CTRL+D) because pressing it will simulate an `EOF` in the `stdin`.

Comment: "because `char` is signed by default" -- it's up to the implementation if it is signed or not. `getchar` and similar functions convert the character they read to `unsigned char` to make it positive and distinct from `EOF` (which is usually -1, but the standard only requires it to be negative).

Comment: @mafso , Right. But now i'm confused ! Does `getchar()` convert the input to `unsigned char` and since it cannot hold -1 (EOF),we use `int`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With 8-bit `char`, a character in a file with the value -1 would be converted to `0xFF` and thus be distinct from `EOF` (as an `int`).

Comment: If the loop ends or not, depends on whether `char` is signed or unsigned. If it's signed, OP's loop ends on `EOF` (but also if a character with value -1 (or whatever `EOF` is) is given as input, so it may break too early); if it's unsigned (the assignment triggers a conversion), it's an endless loop (for the reasons you give). As another note (I've seen many questions asking this, so it should be mentioned to avoid the confusion), ctrl+Z (on MS Windows) only works at the beginning of a line, ctrl+D (for POSIX) must be pressed twice if not at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You have few bugs here.

```
int nc, nw, nl;
```

Should be

```
int nc = 0, nw = 0, nl = 0;


else if (state = OUT){
```

I think you meant

```
else if (state == OUT) {
```

ENTER is 10 not 13.

getchar() on cygwin returns -1 at the end of file (I don't know why). So you can replace EOF with -1.
You can test your program this way: ./program.exe < inputfilename

Answer (score 0):

still having this problem? may have found a solution:
if you type some characters and press ctrl-z, then that ctrl-z counts as a normal character (code 26), but at the beginning of a line (meaning: you don't type anything but the ctrl-z char) it counts as EOF. so:

```
while ( (ch=getchar())!=26 ){
    if (ch==EOF) break;
}
```

this way it doesn't matter where you type the ctrl-z char, the iteration ends.